# How to set the default username and password for LxQt Desktop in Debian

Tags: debian, authentication, lxqt

I am having a Debian system which is having:

```
pstree 

sddm--->Xorg 
      | 
      | -->LxQt
```

where sddm is service running as a combination of Xorg(server) and LxQt(Desktop application).

I want to log in using the default username and password from Lxqt Desktop.
May I please know where I can set this default username and password?

Comment: `sddm` is the display manager that handles the login so I suppose this question is about where to set the default login name in `sddm`?  Do you wish to log in the user automatically?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to default user name and password in sddm.

Comment: OK, do you also wish to log in the user automatically?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to default user name and password in sddm.
Do you wish to log in to the user automatically? ==> No, I wanted to set the default username and password. I wanted to know which file I can set it. 
End goal is , while building Debian distro system using yocto,  I can set this username and password. So that after first boot user can login with default username and passowrd.

Comment: OK, I was too fast and put the answer - please wait and I or someone else can edit it. You can default a username but I am unsure what you mean by "default password".  You cannot pre-fill the password field in the `sddm` login window. Is that what you wanted? Or perhaps: Do you wish to create/edit a user and set that name/password as part of the system setup process? Then that would usually be done outside `sddm`.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to prefill as part of the system process.

Comment: OK, please check whether the Answer helps you to find out how.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `yocto` to build/install a Linux system and wish to add a user to the initial system.  That can be done.  The instructions for that exist in the `yocto` documentation (but are too large to copy here).

Here is a recipe for it:
[openembedded-core: recipe for useradd](https://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta-skeleton/recipes-skeleton/useradd/useradd-example.bb).

Here is a set of slides explaining it:

[Slides about adding custom users to a yocto install](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/images/e/e6/Custom_Users_Groups_in_Yocto1.1.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, I am able to add the using yocto recipes, default username and password.
And , also able to login with default username and password using serial console or ssh console.
e.g.  Star@localhost:/$ cat /etc/passwd | grep Star
Star:x:500:500:,,,:/home/Star:/bin/bash
However, same username, here for example Star, failed to recognize from LXQT Desktop. 
I wanted to know how we can link this default usermane and password to LxQT.
NOTE: After first boot, if I create the some othere login lets see Star1, I can login with Star1 using LxQT Desktop. Thanks.